# Можно ли переназначать клавиши cmd на ctrl для конкретной программы?

Tags: macos

Можно ли поменять непродуманное поведение в mac os когда на стандартные клавиши операций ctrl назначена клавиша cmd, но только для конкретной программы?

Сейчас получается что часть программ требует для операций ctrl, другая часть cmd и итоге в разных программах стандартные операции вставки и удаления выполняются разными комбинациями.

Answer (score 0):

Можно таким образом: `Системные настройки > Клавиатура > Сочетания клавиш приложения` и добавляете, нажав на `+`, в открывшемся диалоге свое сочетание, выбрав из списка приложение.  Также можно сделать это [через командную строку](https://superuser.com/a/545221)

Comment: Не очень понял. Тут предлагается выбрать команду меню которое будет выполняться при нажатии на сочетание. А я спрашиваю о том чтобы для конкретной программы cmd заменялся на ctrl.

Comment: @manking подозреваю, что без сторонних решений такого не добиться (мне таковые неизвестны), хотя ничто не мешает заменить все варианты вручную или написать такую программу самостоятельно, например существует такая вещь как CheatSheet https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/04/18/how-to-view-mac-apps-keyboard-shortcuts/, с помощью которой можно получить список всех сочетаний для конкретной программы, следовательно существует программный способ получить такой список, отфильтровать его на предмет использования Cmd и заменить везде на Ctrl с помощью указанного в ответе способа